# VM or Azure ML for training Deep Learning Algorithms

Tags: azure, gpu, azure-virtual-machine, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to train a deep-learning model for a 512x512 model with TensorFlow. Normally, I would do it with Google Colab or another GPU in the cloud provider. However, due to security reasons, I am going to train the model in Azure which have instances with GPU restricted. My current options are the following:

-Request a **Standard_NC4as_T4_v3** as a computing instance for Azure Machine Learning Studio and train everything in Azure Notebooks. I currently have the dataset there.

-Request an **NC4as_T4_v3** for a VM and get the NVIDIA image to train the model in a VM. Getting the data from Azure Machine Learning Studio is not a problem.

Both options have the T4 GPU (16GB vRAM) because I did similar experiments in the past and it was good for the job. Before requesting access to an instance, I would like to know which option is better and more likely to be accepted.

I've tried to train a model in the currently available computing instances (Tesla K80 and M60), but they don't have enough power and are out of date with the latest libraries. Tried to work with the only GPU instance available at the moment (**NV8as_v4**) but it has an AMD GPU and is not intended for Deep Learning training.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It is about which one is a more accessible choice for training deep learning models in Azure, either VM or Azure Machine Learning studio. The problem is that all GPUs are restricted and I need to request a support ticket which takes some time to have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

VM or ML Studio will not give much difference but the feasibility with Azure ML studio in validation of the images and then we are using the deep learning models. Computational power can be scalable in the form of clusters and instances when we use the azure can be increased in the node count.

[image]

In ML Studio we need to use the attached computes to increase the capacity of the computation.

[image]